# How can I get the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing, return-value, python-multiprocessing

In the example code below, I'd like to get the return value of the function `worker`.  How can I go about doing this?  Where is this value stored?

**Example Code:**

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(procnum):
    '''worker function'''
    print str(procnum) + ' represent!'
    return procnum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    print jobs
```

**Output:**

```
0 represent!
1 represent!
2 represent!
3 represent!
4 represent!
[<Process(Process-1, stopped)>, <Process(Process-2, stopped)>, <Process(Process-3, stopped)>, <Process(Process-4, stopped)>, <Process(Process-5, stopped)>]
```

I can't seem to find the relevant attribute in the objects stored in `jobs`.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Use a [shared variable](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to communicate. For example, like this,

**Example Code:**

```py
import multiprocessing


def worker(procnum, return_dict):
    """worker function"""
    print(str(procnum) + " represent!")
    return_dict[procnum] = procnum


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    print(return_dict.values())
```

**Output:**

```
0 represent!
1 represent!
3 represent!
2 represent!
4 represent!
[0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: I would recommend using a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), rather than a `Manager` here. Using a `Manager` requires spawning an entirely new process, which is overkill when a `Queue` would do.

Comment: @dano : I wonder, if we use Queue() object, we can not sure the order when each process return the value. I mean if we need the order in the result, to do the next work. How could we sure where exactly which output is from which process

Comment: @Catbuilts You could return a tuple from each process, where one value is the actual return value you care about, and the other is a unique identifier from the process. But I also wonder why you need to know which process is returning which value. If that what you actually need to know about the process, or do you need to correlate between your list of inputs and the list of outputs? In that case, I would recommend using `multiprocessing.Pool.map` to process your list of work items.

Comment: this works great to run multiple functions at the same time and a trick to be able to get information after.  =)

Comment: **caveats for functions with only a single argument** : should use `args=(my_function_argument, )`. Note the `,` comma here! Or else Python will complain "missing positional arguments". Took me 10 minutes to figure out. Also check the [manual usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) (under the "process class" section).

Comment: @yuqli:   For those that stumble here and don't know.   The reason for the `(a,)` syntax is because that is how to specify a tuple of len 1   (because just `(a)` is not a tuple).   You could also use `tuple([a])` if that's less confusing.   It "looks more clear" but it's kind of indirect and wasteful.

Comment: @vartec one drawback of using a multipriocessing.Manager() dictionary is that is pickles (serializes) the object it returns, so it has a bottleneck given by the pickle library of maximum 2GiB size for the object to return. Is there any other way of doing this avoiding the serialization of the returning object?

Comment: I was not able to use the multiprocessing Manager while stepping or running through it with a debugger. Therefore I resigned myself to using a multiprocessing Queue instead.

Comment: this makes no sense. how is return_dict being handled outside __main__??

Comment: I dont know why use queue, 'manager.dict()' looks like python, i like it.

Comment: manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
return_dict.values() 
Just hangs for me with no outputs. Any suggestions? Also, my dict has pandas dataframes (parallel analysis of several datasets). Will I have to unpack this to a regular dict when running in parallel (vs when calling the function directly)?

Answer (score 98):

I think the approach [suggested by sega_sai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-get-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-process/10415414#10415414) is the better one. But it really needs a code example, so here goes:

```
import multiprocessing
from os import getpid

def worker(procnum):
    print('I am number %d in process %d' % (procnum, getpid()))
    return getpid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 3)
    print(pool.map(worker, range(5)))
```

Which will print the return values:

```
I am number 0 in process 19139
I am number 1 in process 19138
I am number 2 in process 19140
I am number 3 in process 19139
I am number 4 in process 19140
[19139, 19138, 19140, 19139, 19140]
```

If you are familiar with `map` (the Python 2 built-in) this should not be too challenging. Otherwise have a look at [sega_Sai's link](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult).

Note how little code is needed. (Also note how processes are re-used.)

Comment: Any ideas why my `getpid()` return all the same value? I'm running Python3

Comment: I'm not sure how Pool distributes tasks over workers. Maybe they can all end up at the same worker if they're really fast? Does it happen consistently? Also if you add a delay?

Comment: I also thought it was a speed related thing but when I feed `pool.map` a range of 1,000,000 using more than 10 processes I see at most two different pids.

Comment: Then I'm not sure. I think it'd be interesting to open a separate question for this.

Comment: If the things you want to send a different function to each process, use `pool.apply_async`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult

Comment: if you're using this method, make sure the return value is `Pickle` compatible. Otherwise you'll get "unserializable" errors: https://medium.com/@jwnx/multiprocessing-serialization-in-python-with-pickle-9844f6fa1812

Comment: @mrdaliri You're right, and same for input. In general objects need to serialized in some way to communicate them to another process.

Comment: Out of scope. The question is about using Process (which is less easy than with Pool...)

Comment: @EricH. Alternative solutions are valid answer on stackoverflow. The fact that Pool is easier doesn't make it bad, rather it might be considered an advantage to many users.

Comment: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'foo' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Comment: I use IPython REPL :AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'foo' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Comment: @CSQGB There's no 'foo' in the example code, so you're running something else. Can't help with that, and I'm afraid this comment section isn't the right place for this type of question, sorry.

Comment: This is great until your function takes more than one parameter

Comment: @Frobot You can still use this solution with lambdas or functools.partial, but that's a separate question

Answer (score 69):

For anyone else who is seeking how to get a value from a `Process` using `Queue`:

```
import multiprocessing

ret = {'foo': False}

def worker(queue):
    ret = queue.get()
    ret['foo'] = True
    queue.put(ret)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue.put(ret)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(queue.get())  # Prints {"foo": True}
```

Note that in Windows or Jupyter Notebook, with `multithreading` you have to save this as a file and execute the file. If you do it in a command prompt you will see an error like this:

```
 AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: when i put something in a queue in my worker process my join is never reached. Any idea how this might come?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol do you mean that your main code hangs at p.join() permanently and never continues? Does your process have an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, it hangs there infinitely. My workers all finish (loop within worker function ends, print statement afterwards is printed, for all workers). The join doesn't do anything. If i remove the `Queue` from my function it does let me pass the `join()`

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol Are you perhaps not calling `queue.put(ret)` prior to calling `p.start()` ? In that case, the worker thread will hang at `queue.get()` forever. You can replicate this by copying my snippet above while commenting out `queue.put(ret)`.

Comment: I edited this answer, the `queue.get()` has to happen before the `p.join()`. It works now for me.

Comment: The naming is a bit odd. The `ret` at the top should surely be called `send`, as you're sending it to the process. Although surely simpler just to pass in via the `Process` `args` parameter? Also, if you're only using `put` and `get`, use `SimpleQueue`. Although the code hung for me on Py 3.6.

Comment: @Chris This is a contrived example demonstrating how to get a value from a `process` using a `multiprocessing.queue`.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen appreciate that and your answer was very useful thanks - I copied it into my own below. Just thought calling the outer variable `send` might make the code a tiny bit more readable, as it is being sent and `ret` shadows the inner variable `ret`, which is a different variable, and is actually returned. You could also add a variable to the `args=(queue,)` tuple rather than sending, unless you're moving values around during parallel execution.

Comment: It prints False for me actually

Comment: @Bendemann Someone edited the answer and made it incorrect by placing the `queue.get` before the queue.join. I've fixed it now by placing `queue.get` after `p.join`. Please try again.

Comment: It won't work on Jupyter notebookes btw. Maybe you can also add that in your answer.

Comment: Actually I am getting the same problem as @LaurensKoppenol above. It is hanging at `p.join()` indefinitely. It returns from the callback but it does not execute `queue.get()`

Comment: @Bendemann which version of Python are you using? Can you add a print statement before each line in the `worker` function and confirm its output?

Comment: 3.7.7, yes I already did that and the worker is doing what it is supposed to be doing. Afterwards, it is not executing `queue.get()` after the `p.join()`. So it is stuck in p.join() basically.

Comment: can you put multiple items on the queue?

Answer (score 48):

For some reason, I couldn't find a general example of how to do this with `Queue` anywhere (even Python's doc examples don't spawn multiple processes), so here's what I got working after like 10 tries:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def add_helper(queue, arg1, arg2): # the func called in child processes
    ret = arg1 + arg2
    queue.put(ret)

def multi_add(): # spawns child processes
    q = Queue()
    processes = []
    rets = []
    for _ in range(0, 100):
        p = Process(target=add_helper, args=(q, 1, 2))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        ret = q.get() # will block
        rets.append(ret)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    return rets
```

`Queue` is a blocking, thread-safe queue that you can use to store the return values from the child processes. So you have to pass the queue to each process. Something less obvious here is that you have to `get()` from the queue before you `join` the `Process`es or else the queue fills up and blocks everything.

**Update** for those who are object-oriented (tested in Python 3.4):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Multiprocessor():

    def __init__(self):
        self.processes = []
        self.queue = Queue()

    @staticmethod
    def _wrapper(func, queue, args, kwargs):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        queue.put(ret)

    def run(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        args2 = [func, self.queue, args, kwargs]
        p = Process(target=self._wrapper, args=args2)
        self.processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    def wait(self):
        rets = []
        for p in self.processes:
            ret = self.queue.get()
            rets.append(ret)
        for p in self.processes:
            p.join()
        return rets

# tester
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp = Multiprocessor()
    num_proc = 64
    for _ in range(num_proc): # queue up multiple tasks running `sum`
        mp.run(sum, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    ret = mp.wait() # get all results
    print(ret)
    assert len(ret) == num_proc and all(r == 15 for r in ret)
```

Answer (score 41):

This example shows how to use a list of [multiprocessing.Pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) instances to return strings from an arbitrary number of processes:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(procnum, send_end):
    '''worker function'''
    result = str(procnum) + ' represent!'
    print result
    send_end.send(result)

def main():
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []
    for i in range(5):
        recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, send_end))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    result_list = [x.recv() for x in pipe_list]
    print result_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
0 represent!
1 represent!
2 represent!
3 represent!
4 represent!
['0 represent!', '1 represent!', '2 represent!', '3 represent!', '4 represent!']
```

This solution uses fewer resources than a [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) which uses

- a Pipe
- at least one Lock
- a buffer
- a thread

or a [multiprocessing.SimpleQueue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue) which uses

- a Pipe
- at least one Lock

It is very instructive to look at the source for each of these types.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that without making the pipes a global variable?

Comment: I put all the global data and code into a main function and it works the same. Does that answer your question?

Comment: does the pipe always have to be read before any new value can be added (sent) to it?

Comment: +1, good answer. But about the solution being more efficient, the tradeoff is that you're making one `Pipe` per process vs one `Queue` for all processes. I don't know if that ends up being more efficient in all cases.

Comment: This answer causes a deadlock if the returning object is large. Instead of doing the proc.join() first I would first try to recv() the return value and then do the join.

Comment: @L.Pes You will have to back that statement up with an example that proves it.

Comment: I am with @L.Pes on this. Could be OS-specific, but I adapted this example to my  use case and workers trying to send_end.send(result) for large result would hang indefinitely. Joining after receiving fixed it. Happy to provide an example if N=2 is too anecdotal for you.

Comment: @Vlad I think you misunderstand me. I am more than happy to change the answer, but if this is a real problem, then you should be able to post code that allows others to duplicate it, diagnose it, and provide a modified answer that may be even better than merely adding a `recv`.

Comment: Pipes rock! They're easy to use and understand :)

Answer (score 18):

It seems that you should use the [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) class instead and use the methods .apply() .apply_async(), map()

Reference: *[class multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult)*

Comment: I have tensorflow code for which multiprocessing.Pool will hang but not multiprocessing.Process

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `exit` built-in to set the exit code of a process. It can be obtained from the `exitcode` attribute of the process:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(procnum):
    print str(procnum) + ' represent!'
    exit(procnum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    result = []
    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
        result.append(proc.exitcode)
    print result
```

**Output:**

```
0 represent!
1 represent!
2 represent!
3 represent!
4 represent!
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Be warned that this approach could become confusing. Processes should generally exit with exit code 0 is they completed without error. If you have anything monitoring your system process exit codes then you may see these reported as errors.

Comment: Perfect if you just want to raise an exception in the parent process on error.

Answer (score 12):

The [pebble](https://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/) package has a nice abstraction leveraging `multiprocessing.Pipe` which makes this quite straightforward:

```py
from pebble import concurrent

@concurrent.process
def function(arg, kwarg=0):
    return arg + kwarg

future = function(1, kwarg=1)

print(future.result())
```

Example from: https://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/#concurrent-decorators

Answer (score 11):

Thought I'd simplify the simplest examples copied from above, working for me on Py3.6. Simplest is [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print(pool.map(worker, range(10)))
```

You can set the number of processes in the pool with, e.g., `Pool(processes=5)`. However it defaults to CPU count, so leave it blank for CPU-bound tasks. (I/O-bound tasks often suit threads anyway, as the threads are mostly waiting so can share a CPU core.) `Pool` also applies [chunking optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032744/1308967).

(Note that the worker method cannot be nested within a method. I initially defined my worker method inside the method that makes the call to `pool.map`, to keep it all self-contained, but then the processes couldn't import it, and threw "AttributeError: Can't pickle local object outer_method..inner_method". More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283968/1308967). It can be inside a class.)

(Appreciate the original question specified printing `'represent!'` rather than `time.sleep()`, but without it I thought some code was running concurrently when it wasn't.)

---

Py3's [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) is also two lines (`.map` returns a generator so you need the `list()`):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    print(list(executor.map(worker, range(10))))
```

---

With plain [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)es:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(x, queue):
    time.sleep(1)
    queue.put(x)

queue = multiprocessing.SimpleQueue()
tasks = range(10)

for task in tasks:
    multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(task, queue,)).start()

for _ in tasks:
    print(queue.get())
```

Use [`SimpleQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) if all you need is `put` and `get`. The first loop starts all the processes, before the second makes the blocking `queue.get` calls. I don't think there's any reason to call `p.join()` too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python 3, you can use [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) as a convenient abstraction:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def worker(procnum):
    '''worker function'''
    print(str(procnum) + ' represent!')
    return procnum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print(list(executor.map(worker, range(5))))
```

Output:

```
0 represent!
1 represent!
2 represent!
3 represent!
4 represent!
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**ProcessPoolExecutor**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) to get a return value from a function as shown below:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def test(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    feature = executor.submit(test, 2, 3)
    print(feature.result()) # 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
import multiprocessing

output=[]
data = range(0,10)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(64)
    r=p.map(f, data)
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output.append(handler())

print(output[0])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified [vartec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-get-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-process/10415215#10415215) a bit since I needed to get the error codes from the function.  (Thanks vartec!!! It's an awesome trick.)

This can also be done with a `manager.list`, but I think is better to have it in a dict and store a list within it.  That way, way we keep the function and the results since we can't be sure of the order in which the list will be populated.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import datetime
import multiprocessing


def func1(fn, m_list):
    print 'func1: starting'
    time.sleep(1)
    m_list[fn] = "this is the first function"
    print 'func1: finishing'
    # return "func1"  # No need for return since Multiprocess doesn't return it =(

def func2(fn, m_list):
    print 'func2: starting'
    time.sleep(3)
    m_list[fn] = "this is function 2"
    print 'func2: finishing'
    # return "func2"

def func3(fn, m_list):
    print 'func3: starting'
    time.sleep(9)
    # If fail won't join the rest because it never populate the dict
    # or do a try/except to get something in return.
    raise ValueError("failed here")
    # if we want to get the error in the manager dict we can catch the error
    try:
        raise ValueError("failed here")
        m_list[fn] = "this is third"
    except:
        m_list[fn] = "this is third and it fail horrible"
        # print 'func3: finishing'
        # return "func3"


def runInParallel(*fns):  # * is to accept any input in list
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    proc = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    m_list = manager.dict()
    for fn in fns:
        # print fn
        # print dir(fn)
        p = Process(target=fn, name=fn.func_name, args=(fn, m_list))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()  # 5 is the time-out

    print datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    return m_list, proc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager, proc = runInParallel(func1, func2, func3)
    # print dir(proc[0])
    # print proc[0]._name
    # print proc[0].name
    # print proc[0].exitcode

    # Here you can check what did fail
    for i in proc:
        print i.name, i.exitcode  # 'name' was set up in the Process line 53

    # Here will only show the function that worked and where able to populate the
    # manager dict
    for i, j in manager.items():
        print dir(i)  # Things you can do to the function
        print i, j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use decorator for printing result of function

def printer(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(result)
        return result
    return inner


@printer
def cube(nums: list):
    result = []
    for v in nums:
        result.append(v ** 3)
    return result




if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [2, 3, 4, 6]
    p1 = Process(target=square, args=(nums,))
    p2 = Process(target=cube, args=(nums,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```