# How to return a counter dictionary from a function passed to multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, return, counter, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of CSV files. I want to do a set of operations on each of them and then produce a counter dict and i want to cerate a master list containing individual counter dict from all CSV files. I want to parallelize processing each of the csv file and then return the counter dict from each file. I found a similar solution here : [How can I recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce/28799109)

I used the solution suggested by David Cullen.  This solution works perfectly for strings, but when I tried to return a counter dict or a normal dict. All the CSV files are processed until the send_end.send(result) and it hangs on there forever when executed and then throws a memory error. I am running this in a Linux server with more than sufficient memory for creating the list of counter dicts.

I used the following code:

```
import multiprocessing

#get current working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()

#take a list of all files in cwd
files = os.listdir(cwd)

#defining the function that needs to be done on all csv files
def worker(f,send_end):
    infile= open(f) 
    #read liens in csv file
    lines = infile.readlines()
    #split the lines by "," and store it in a list of lists
    master_lst = [line.strip().split(“,”) for line in lines]
    #extract the second field in each sublist 
    counter_lst = [ element[1] for element in master_lst]
    print “Total elements in the list” + str(len(counter_lst))
    #create a dictionary of count elements
    a = Counter(counter_lst)
    # return the counter dict
    send_end.send(a)

def main():
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
           recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
           p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(f, send_end))
           jobs.append(p)
           pipe_list.append(recv_end)
           p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
       proc.join()
    result_list = [x.recv() for x in pipe_list]
    print len(result_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

The error that i get is the following:

```
Process Process-42:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in 
  _bootstrap
  self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/amm/python/collapse_multiprocessing_return.py", line 32, in 
  worker
  a = Counter(counter_lst)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 444, in __init__
  self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 526, in update
  self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
 MemoryError
 Process Process-17:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 Process Process-6:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in 
 _bootstrap
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in 
 _bootstrap
 Process Process-8:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in 
 _bootstrap
 self.run()
 self.run()
 self.run()
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
 File "/home/amm/python/collapse_multiprocessing_return.py", line 32, in 
 worker
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/home/amm/python/collapse_multiprocessing_return.py", line 32, in 
 worker
 File "/home/amm/python/collapse_multiprocessing_return.py", line 32, in 
 worker
 a = Counter(counter_lst_lst)
 a = Counter(counter_lst_lst)
 a = Counter(counter_lst_lst)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 444, in __init__
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 444, in __init__
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 444, in __init__
 self.update(iterable, **kwds)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 526, in update
 self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
 MemoryError
 self.update(iterable, **kwds)
 self.update(iterable, **kwds)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 526, in update
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 526, in update
 self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
 self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
 MemoryError
 MemoryError
 Process Process-10:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in 
 _bootstrap
 self.run()
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/home/amm/python/collapse_multiprocessing_return.py", line 32, in 
 worker
 a = Counter(counter_lst)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 444, in __init__
 self.update(iterable, **kwds)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 526, in update
 self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
 MemoryError
 ^Z
 [18]+  Stopped                 collapse_multiprocessing_return.py
```

Now instead of "a" in send_end.send(a) if i replace f, the filename. It prints the number of csv files in the directory (which is what len(result_list) does in this case). But when the counter dict "a" is returned it gets stuck forever, throwing the above error.

I would like to have the code pass the counter dict to receive end without any error/problems. Is there a work around? Could someone please suggest a possible solution?

p.s: I am new to multiprocessing module, sorry if this question sounds naive. Also, i tried the multiprocessing.Manager(), but got a similar error

Comment: 1. Your error message is missing. 2. Please provide a [mcve] that we can run ourselves.

Comment: @AlexHall: Now i have included the entire message log until i terminated the script from running further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your traceback mentions `Process Process-42:`, so there are at least 42 processes being created. You're creating a process for every CSV file, which is not useful and is probably causing the memory error.

Your problem can be solved much more simply using `multiprocessing.Pool.map`. The `worker` function can also be shortened greatly:

```
def worker(f):
    with open(f) as infile:
        return Counter(line.strip().split(",")[1]
                       for line in infile)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result_list = pool.map(worker, [f for f in files if f.endswith('.csv')])
```

Passing no arguments to the pool means it'll create as many processes as you have CPU cores. Using more may or may not increase performance.

Comment: Thanks. Seems i complicated things myself. Thanks for the cleaner code