# Python multiprocessing pool memory issues, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, out-of-memory, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to process a large number of files with a library called Bleualign using Python's multi-processing pool.

I am getting memory errors after a few hours, is there something I am doing wrong with how I am multiprocessing below?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, glob
from multiprocessing import Pool
number_of_workers = 4

def bleualign(file):
    cmd = "python3 '../bleualign/bleualign.py' -s ../4a_zh-tokenized-converted/"+file+" -t '../3_en-tokenized/"+file+"' --srctotarget './"+file+"' -o '../5_aligned-zh/"+file+"'"
    try:
        os.system(cmd)
    except:
        print('error')

files = []
os.chdir("./4b_zh-tokenized-sample-en")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    files.append(file)


mypool = Pool(number_of_workers)
mypool.map(bleualign, files)
```

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: No this is on Mac, does it matter?

Comment: Would have been [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52693216/9059420) on Windows.