# Example from documentaion doesn't work in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, multithreading, jupyter-notebook

I had looked at the documentaion. And there was an example

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

The problem is: it is not working. I run this code in Jupiter Notebook cell. And this the cell doesn't raise any exception. But Jupiter's terminal does. And it says: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693216/multiprocessing-pool-example-does-not-work-and-freeze-the-kernel) the problem may be because I don't use `__name__ == '__main__'` condition. But I do.

I had literally copy and paste example from the documention and it's not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are running on Windows. If so, this is a known issue. See [this article](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac). You need to add your function `f` to a file, such as `worker.py`:

**worker.py**

```
def f(x):
    return x*x
```

Then you jupyter notebook code becomes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import worker


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(worker.f, [1, 2, 3]))
```