# Pool.apply_async(): nested function is not executed

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am getting familiar with Python's `multiprocessing` module. The following code works as expected:

```
#outputs 0 1 2 3
from multiprocessing import Pool
def run_one(x):
    print x
    return

pool = Pool(processes=12)
for i in range(4):
    pool.apply_async(run_one, (i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Now, however, if I wrap a function around the above code, the `print` statements are not executed (or the output is redirected at least):

```
#outputs nothing
def run():
    def run_one(x):
        print x
        return    

    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    for i in range(4):    
        pool.apply_async(run_one, (i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If I move the `run_one` definition outside of `run`, the output is the expected one again, when I'm calling `run()`:

```
#outputs 0 1 2 3
def run_one(x):
    print x
    return

def run():    
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    for i in range(4):       
        pool.apply_async(run_one, (i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

What am I missing here? Why isn't the second snippet printing anything? If I simply call the `run_one(i)` function instead of using `apply_async`, all the three codes output the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pool needs to pickle (serialize) everything it sends to its worker-processes. Pickling actually only saves the name of a function and unpickling requires re-importing the function by name.
For that to work, the function needs to be defined at the top-level, nested functions won't be importable by the child and already trying to pickle them raises an exception:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import _ForkingPickler

def run():
    def foo(x):
        pass
    _ForkingPickler.dumps(foo)  # multiprocessing custom pickler;
                                # same effect with pickle.dumps(foo)

run()
# Out:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'run.<locals>.foo'
```

The reason why you don't see an exception is, because `Pool` already starts catching exceptions during pickling tasks in the parent and only re-raises them when you call `.get()` on the `AsyncResult` object you immediately get when you call `pool.apply_async()`.

That's why (with Python 2) you better always use it like this, even if your target-function doesn't return anything (still returns implicit `None`):

```
    results = [pool.apply_async(foo, (i,)) for i in range(4)]
    # `pool.apply_async()` immediately returns AsyncResult (ApplyResult) object
    for res in results:
        res.get()
```

Non-async Pool-methods like `Pool.map()` and `Pool.starmap()` use the same (asynchronous) low-level functions under the hood like their asynchronous siblings, but they additionally call `.get()` for you, so you will always see an exception with these methods.

Python 3 has an `error_callback`-parameter for asynchronous Pool-methods you can use instead to handle exceptions.