# Multiprocessing pool map: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, mathematical-optimization, python-multithreading

I have a really similar problem to
[Python Multiprocessing Pool Map: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265120/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object)

I think I understand where the problem is, I am just not sure how to fix it. "Pool.map" needs a top level function as input. But i dont know how i can rewrite this problem:

A simplified code version:

```
import os as os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
def opti_fun_data(prediction):
    def opti_fun(x):
        def error_fun(i):
            return error_fun_opti(x,prediction,i)
        try:
            pool = Pool(np.max([os.cpu_count()-1,1]))
            error = np.mean(pool.map(error_fun, range(M)))
        finally: # To make sure processes are closed in the end, even if errors happen
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        return error
    return opti_fun
```

If I run
`opti_fun_data(prediction)(x0)` 
i get

`Can't pickle local object 'opti_fun_data.<locals>.opti_fun.<locals>.error_fun'`

I am new to the multiprocessing library and could use a helping hand.
For those who are interested in a bit of background: 
I want to minimize the function "opti_fun" for a bunch of different scenarios/predictions. Calculating my error measure/benchmark ("error_fun_opti") is quiete computitional intensive, therefore i try to parallelize this step.

Comment: fyi. instead of using a `try-finally` block, you can use a `with` block to ensure the processes close: `with Pool(size) as pool:`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lift the function to the top level and use `functools.partial` to provide the scoped values rather than nested scope.

```
def error_fun(x, prediction, i):
    return error_fun_opti(x, prediction, i)

error = np.mean(pool.map(functools.partial(error_fun, x, prediction), range(M)))
```

Comment: thx buddy! I wasn't aware that there is a partial evaluation of a function. You helped me more than you think.