# Iterating over an array multithreaded

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some difficulties finding out how to write the following code multi threaded. I guess its just a syntax thing how to write it probably.

What I want is to process every `col` parallel, every col has their `vfc` - array in the same `data` object.

Thanks in advance

```
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:

            for col in list_column_names:
                # returns an array
                vfc = self.get_vfc(col)

                data[vfc] = data[col].apply(lambda x: self.smth(x, self.model))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not using the pool you create. Also, working with lambda expressions in multiprocessing can be problematic, cf. 
[Python Multiprocessing Pool Map: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265120/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object)
You could try something like this:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:      
   pool.map(self.cf, [data[c] for c in data])
```

where the function `cf` is defined at class level and contains the logic intended by the use of `apply` and your lambda. Possibly also define your dataframe at class level.

Comment: yeah had this lambda issue before :/ so the dataframe as variable is not possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by variable, but you could define/compute the dataframe ```data``` before the multiprocessing operation. For instance, something like this would work
```
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            new_data = pool.map(self.cf, [data[c] for c in data])
            new_keys = pool.map(self.get_vfc, [data[c] for c in data])

        for i, k in enumerate(new_keys):
            data[k] = new_data[i]
```
(sorry about the poor formatting, block code doesn't work in comments...)