# getting the return value of a function used in multiprocess

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Say I have the below code, a function that does something, which is initiated in a Process, and returns a value.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def my_func(arg):
    return 'Hello, ' + arg

p1 = Process(target=my_func, args=('John',)
p1.start()
p1.join()
```

How do I get the return value of the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce)

Comment: This might help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

Q = Queue()

def my_func(arg):
    Q.put('Hello, ' + arg)

p1 = Process(target=my_func, args=('John',))
p1.start()
print(Q.get())
p1.join()
```

Comment: Please add the missing brackets: Queue(), Process(target=my_func, args=('John',)).

Comment: This implies to modify your original `my_func` adding Q if you want to use it parallel

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Queue` of `multiprocessing` to `my_func()` as shown below:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def my_func(arg, q):
    q.put('Hello, ' + arg)
    
queue = Queue()                            # Here
p1 = Process(target=my_func, args=('John', queue))
p1.start()
print(queue.get())
p1.join()
```

This is the result below:

```
Hello, John
```

Be careful, if using `queue` module below with process, the program doesn't work properly:

```py
import queue
queue = queue.Queue()
```

So, just use `Queue` of `multiprocessing` module with process as I used in the code above:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
queue = Queue()
```