# Pandas Dataframe doesnt update when running Multiprocessing code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, screen-scraping

I'm trying to update a dataframe (self.df) with a column from a temp df(self.df_temp['linkedin_profile']) with the following class but it doesn't seem to update anything.
The code:

```
class NameToSocialURLScraper:


def __init__(self, csv_file_name, person_name_column, organization_name_column):
    self.proxy_list = PROXY_LIST
    pool = Pool()
    self.csv_file_name = csv_file_name
    self.person_name_column = person_name_column
    self.organization_name_column = organization_name_column
    self.df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_name)
    self.df_temp = pd.DataFrame()

def internal_linkedin_job(self):
    self.df['linkedin_profile'] = np.nan
    self.df_temp['linkedin_profile'] = np.nan
    self.df_temp['linkedin_profile'] = self.df.apply(
        lambda row: term_scraper(
            str(row[self.person_name_column]) + " " + str(row[self.organization_name_column]), self.proxy_list,
            'link', output_generic=False), axis=1)
    self.df['linkedin_profile'] = self.df_temp['linkedin_profile']
    print(self.df.values)

...

def multiprocess_job(self):
    multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
    linkedin_profile_proc = Process(target=self.internal_linkedin_job, args=())
    jobs = [linkedin_profile_proc]
    # Start the processes (i.e. calculate the random number lists)
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    # Ensure all of the processes have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

When printing inside internal_linkedin_job it shows the df with the new column 'linkedin_profile' but when I print after j.join() the column isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing multiprocessing, each process runs in its own memory space. You would need to refactor your code so that internal_linkedin_job returns the dataframe.

Comment: Got it! solved it with Queue with the help of the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582535/5352085