# Get the returned value (string) of a function without modifying it when calling it through the multiprocessing libary

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615502/getting-the-return-value-of-a-function-used-in-multiprocess), in [Python](https://www.python.org/), one can retrieve the returned value (a variable length string) of a function using a [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). But this involve to actually *modify* the function *itself* (by returning `Q.put(retval)` instead of `retval`).

What if one **cannot** modify the function (e.g. because it's was design as it is, also for other purposes such as an other usage which doesn't involve a call to a new thread)? Is it still possible to easily get the returned string value from this function when calling it through the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library? And if yes, how?

Comment: wrap the original function (the one you cant modify) with a new func that can put the result in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one answer is rather simple. If you cannot modify the function itself, you can wrap it in a new one, e.g.:

```
def function_wraper(**kwargs):
    Q.put(unmodified_function(**kwargs))
```

And then, calling it as follows:

```
import multiprocessing

def unmodified_function(**kwargs):
    return ', '.join([f'{v}' for v in kwargs.values()])+' !'

def run_function_as_new_thread(func=unmodified_function, args=(), kwargs=None):
    procs = []
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=func,
        args=args,
        kwargs=kwargs,
        name = (f"Process")
    )
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    return True

kwargs = {"hello": "Bonjour", "world": "le monde"}
Q = multiprocessing.Queue() # Q has to be defined before using function_wraper()
_ = run_function_as_new_thread(
    func=function_wraper,
    args = (),
    kwargs=kwargs
)
if not Q.empty():
    resulting_string = Q.get()
    print(resulting_string)
else:
    print('nothing to print...')
```

This will print `Bonjour le monde !`.

In my case this is working because my function is accepting `kwargs`, so you'll probably have to tweak if your function also have `args`.