# I want to call functions from second python environment in my my first python environment. Is this possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, virtualenv, environment

I am developing a virtual assistant. I am using google_speech_to_text converter i am unable to keep the audio input continues. I think if there is any way i can use two environments, one will be used for listening and converting text and other for rest of the processing.

I don't want to change my STT engine. i just want to know is it possible to simultaneously switch between environments. If yes, HOW?

Here is my input.py file :  whereever I require to take audio input I call the function `start_listening()`:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import output
import winsound

def start_listening():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        # output.speak("Listening")
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.record(source, duration=5)

        try:
            return r.recognize_google(audio)
        except:
            output.speak("Unable to Translate, speak again")
            start_listening()
```

Here is my processing.py file :

```
import input as listener
import output as speak
import clock
import query_processor as mind
import rideBooking

#First Greeting at the startup , according to the time select the greeting
speak.speak(clock.get_part_of_day())

def searching_for_word(word,sentence):
    if word in sentence:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main_organ():
    input = listener.start_listening()
    inputType = mind.classify(input)
    if inputType == 'whatever':
        #run different functions on different commands
        main_organ()


#run the app with the below code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_organ()
```

While the processing is ON the app is unable to listen. It can only start_listening when the processing is fully completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple processes.

To do that, import the [`multiprocessing.Process.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) module and [recover the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce).

You can use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to process the data as it comes from your subprocess.

You don't need multiple environments.

Comment: i want the processing be done at the background without interrupting the input processing.

Comment: like if the processing needs 2 minutes to process something during that period the input should work fine and watches for the commands

Comment: multiprocessing does that. Put the data to process in a queue, and process it in another process. The processing process will process the data without interrupting other processes.

Comment: Can you please help me with a example