# Return a list from multiprocessor thread- TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, multithreading

So my aim is to use multiprocessing to run a function that returns a list, but kill the thread if it is taking too long. Here is my code, inspired primarily by this post:

[How can I recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce)

```
def scrapeBank(bankName, return_dict)
    # [do some stuff that generates list of transactions]
    return_dict[transactions] = transactions

TIMEOUT = 60 # seconds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=scrapeBank, args=('bankName',return_dict))
    p.start()

    p.join(TIMEOUT)

    if p.is_alive():
        print('function terminated')
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

    print return_dict.values()
```

When I run this I get 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''. I have googled this error and unfortunately really struggle to understand what it is telling me (I am new to python).

Very open to an alternate way of killing a function that takes too long that avoids the multiprocessing tuff.

Comment: You usually get this error when you are trying to insert a modifiable object (list, set, ...) into a container that does not allow it (values of a set, keys of a dict, ...).

Comment: Is there a way of passing a variable back to my main thread without using a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the line `return_dict[transactions] = transactions`

Python Dict requires keys to be immutable (i.e. not changeable).

A python List `transactions` is mutable, therefore you cant use it as a key `return_dict[transactions]`.

Make it a string `return_dict['transactions'] = transactions`.

Comment: That seems to work!! You are a hero among men. I guess I should look up what a Dict is!!

Comment: A dict is a dictionary, and yes, you should read more about python data types.