# Passing dictionary to two subprocesses in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've got two functions that I call in a thread each passing in the same dictionary that they add to. I also have a third function that runs outside of the thread after both the threaded functions finish that also adds items into the dictionary.

When I check the contents of the dictionary, it only contains the contents of the third function. An example of what I'm talking about is below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

my_dict = {}

process1 = Process(target=class1.run, args=(my_dict,))
process2 = Process(target=class2.run, args=(my_dict,))

process1.start()
process2.start()

process1.join()
process2.join()

class3.run(my_dict)

print(my_dict)
```

What's the workaround to allow me to pass the dictionary to each function (threaded or not) and ensure all values are inserted?

Comment: The answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `multiprocessing`. It spins up new `Processes` for each of the functions that you're calling. Unlike, `threading`, processes don't hare a memory space. Each of the two processes you're spinning up will get a copy of `my_dict`. Hence the modifications made to `my_dict` from `process1` or `proces2` will not not be visible to the `my_dict` in `class3` (since they are different objects in different memory spaces)

If you want to share information between processes you can use `Queues` - let each Process send the modified dict back in a queue message, and then merge then before passing it to `class3`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues

Or if you actually meant to use `threads` you need to switch to using the `threading` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html (Be aware of the GIL in this case)

Comment: That's the one mate... thanks very much man. I changed it to threading instead and it worked.