# transfer the outputs of the first function to the second in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My code consists of three major parts:

1-There are two functions whose second function depends on the outputs of the first function

2-And these two are in a ***while***

```
def ff(x,y):
   do something
return h,b

def qq(h,b):
   do something
return z

while True:
   p1 = process(target=ff, args = (x,y))
   p2 = process(target=qq, args = (h,b))

   do something
   .
   .
   .
```

Now I'm going to run these two functions in multiprocess but I don't know how to transfer the outputs of the first function to the second

Thanks

Comment: some code and a little more details will be helpful here. A [mre] is needed. Take a look in [ask] to improve your question to better attract quality answers

Comment: thanks for your attention. i've edited it.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce) will answer your question. It will give you a way to retrieve the return value from the function passed to the process and from there I'm sure you will be able to get your desired outcome