# How to check return values of a function passed to process multi threading

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i have created a sample code to run multiple functions at same time ad its works but i am unable to get the return values.
So how to check the return values.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

a= 10;
b=20;
def calculate_sum(x,y):
    print('start sum')
    c = x+y
    #print(c)
    #print('end sum')
    #print(c)
    return c

def calculate_subst(x,y):
    print('start subt')
    v = y-x
    
    #print('end sum')
    return v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=calculate_sum,args=(a,b))
    p1.start()
    
    p2 = Process(target=calculate_subst,args=(a,b))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: NB: there are many different ways to do this, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59486541/984421) summarises of some of the simpler solutions.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for it, but i want output of both the function at the same time. so please help on this.

Comment: Then use a queue, or any of the other solutions shown in the linked question.