# Python Multiprocessing: executing a function with randomness multiple times and getting identical results

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, return

In the example code below, I was trying to adapt the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce). The goal is to use multi-processing to generate independent random normal numbers (in the example below I just want 3 random numbers). This is a baby version of any more complicated code where some random number generator is used in defining the trial function.

**Example Code**

```
import multiprocessing

def trial(procnum, return_dict):
    p = np.random.randn(1)
    num = procnum
    return_dict[procnum] = p, num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=trial, args=(i,return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    print(return_dict.values())
```

However, the output gives me the same random number every time, rather than an independent random number for each entry in return_dict.

**Output**

```
[(array([-1.08817286]), 0), (array([-1.08817286]), 1), (array([-1.08817286]), 2)]
```

I feel like this is a really silly mistake. Can someone expose my silliness please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a silly mistake, and it has to do with the way `numpy` does the staging across cores. Read more here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-numpy-random-rand-produce-the-same-values-in-different-cores/12005

But the solution is to give `numpy` a random seed from a large range:

```py
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import random

def trial(procnum, return_dict):
    np.random.seed(random.randint(0,100000))
    p = np.random.randn()
    return_dict[procnum] = p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=trial, args=(i,return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    print(return_dict.values())
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but I recommend seeding from a _much_ larger range; for example, `random.randrange(1 << 1000)`.Current versions of Python and numpy exploit integer seeds of any size, and unintended collisions are too likely with a small range ("birthday paradox")

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a gloss to @Aziz Sonawalla's answer: why does this work?

Because Python's `random` module works differently.  On Windows, multiprocessing spawns new processes, and each is a freshly created instance that does its own from-scratch seeding from OS sources of entropy.

On Linux, by default multiprocessing uses `fork()` to create new processes, and those inherit the entire state of the main process, in copy-on-write mode. That includes the state of the random number generator. So you *would* get the same random numbers across worker processes from Python too, except that, at least since Python 3.7, Python explicitly (but under the covers - invisibly) re-seeds its random number generator after `fork()`.

I'm not sure when, but for some time before 3.7 the multiprocessing `Process` implementation also re-seeded Python's generator in child processes it created via `fork()` (but Python itself did *not* if you called `fork()` yourself).

All of which is just to explain why calling Python's `random.randrange()` returns different results in different worker processes.  That's why it's an effective way to generate differing seeds for `numpy` to use in this context.