# Barrier in Multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on multiprocessing in Python and I am stuck at this point.I want to put the a barrier so that all previous activities are performed first. This pseudocode will be better for understanding

```
def func1:
     #does something and returns something

def func2:
     #does something and returns something

    if __name__=='__main__':
         p1 = Process(target = func1)
         result = []
         result.append(p1.start())
         p2 = Process(target = func2)
         result.append(p2.start())
        # A Barrier here so that above all statments must be executed before the next one
         print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`Process.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Process.join)

You would use it like this:

```py
def func1:
     #does something and returns something

def func2:
     #does something and returns something

if __name__=='__main__':
     p1 = Process(target = func1)
     result = []
     result.append(p1.start())
     p2 = Process(target = func2)
     result.append(p2.start())
     p1.join()
     p2.join()
     print(result)
```

Also the way you're capturing the results from the function is incorrect. Look at this answer for details on how to retrieve results from a process: [How can I recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce)

Comment: Can you point me that will my result variable will have the return values of the function? I am getting none in this case.

Comment: I've added a link to another answer that addresses that