# How do I get multiprocessing results?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I would like to store the result of the work in a specific variable after multiprocessing as shown below.

Alternatively, I want to save the results of the job as a csv file. May I know how to do it?

This is my code:

(I want to get 'df4' and 'df7' data and to save csv file)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import time
import multiprocessing

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df5 = pd.DataFrame()
df6 = pd.DataFrame()
df7 = pd.DataFrame()
df8 = pd.DataFrame()

date = '2011-03', '2011-02' ........ '2021-03'    #There are 120 list.
list1 = df1['resion'].drop_duplicates()  # There are 20 list. 'df1' is original data

#I'd like to divide the list and work on it. 
list11 = list1.iloc[0:10]
list12 = list1.iloc[10:20]

#It's a function using 'list11'.
def cal1():
    global df2
    global df3
    global df4

    start = time.time()

    for i, t in enumerate(list11):    
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['resion'] == t])  #'df1' is original data

        if i%2 == 0:
            print ("cal1 function processing: ", i)
            end = time.time()
            print (end-start)

        else:
            pass

        for n, d in enumerate(date):               
            df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2[df2['date'] == d])
            df3['number'] = df3['price'].rank(pct=True, ascending = False )
            df4 = df4.append(pd.DataFrame(df3))

        return df4

#It's a function using 'list12'.

def cal2():
    global df5
    global df6
    global df7

    start = time.time()

    for i, t in enumerate(list12):    
        df5 = pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['resion'] == t])  #'df1' is original data

        if i%2 == 0:
            print ("cal1 function processing: ", i)
            end = time.time()
            print (end-start)

        else:
            pass

        for n, d in enumerate(date):               
            df6 = pd.DataFrame(df5[df5['date'] == d])
            df6['number'] = df6['price'].rank(pct=True, ascending = False )
            df7 = df7.append(pd.DataFrame(df6))

        return df7

## Multiprocessing code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating processes
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cal1, args=())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cal2, args=())
  
    # starting process 1
    p1.start()
    # starting process 2
    p2.start()
  
    # wait until process 1 is finished
    p1.join()
    
    # wait until process 2 is finished
    p2.join()
  
    # both processes finished
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your functions `cal1` and `cal2` are identical except that they are trying to assign results to some different global variables.  This is not going to work, because when you run them in a subprocess, they will assign that global variable in the subprocess, but that will have no impact whatsoever on the main process from which you started them.

If you want to map a function to multiple input ranges across multiple processes you can use a process [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) and [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map).

For example:

```py
def cal(input_list):
    start = time.time()

    for i, t in enumerate(input_list):    
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['resion'] == t])  #'df1' is original data

        if i%2 == 0:
            print ("cal1 function processing: ", i)
            end = time.time()
            print (end-start)

        else:
            pass

        for n, d in enumerate(date):               
            df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2[df2['date'] == d])
            df3['number'] = df3['price'].rank(pct=True, ascending = False )
            df4 = df4.append(pd.DataFrame(df3))

        # I kept your original code unmodified but I'm not really sure this
        # is what to do, because you are returning after one pass through the
        # outer loop.  I haven't scrutinized what you are actually trying to
        # do but I suspect this is wrong too.
        return df4
```

Then create a process pool and you can divide up the input how you want (or, with a bit of tweaking, you can let `Pool.map` chunk the input for you, and then *reduce* the outputs from map into a single output):

```py
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
dfs = pool.map(cal, [list1.iloc[0:10], list1.iloc[10:20]])
```

This is just to get you started.  I would probably do a number of other things differently as well.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried the code you told me. However, 'for loop' does not work.  Only the first 'list' works......  (I mean , list1.iloc[0:1], list1.iloc[10:11])

Comment: Yes, see the comment I added in my copy of your code.  The way you coded your loop in `cal1` and `cal2` is buggy because it returns from the loop after one iteration, but that's unrelated to the question about multiprocessing.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation.
It was very helpful.