# Function running as a timer goes down?

Tags: python, function, math, testing, timer

I'm really new to programming and I'm trying to create a maths quiz for young children. They have to answer as many questions as they can in 60 seconds. I have a timer and a question generator

The problem is however, I cant get them to run at the same time, for example, the program waits for 1 second, asks a question, waits until the user has answered it, then carries on with the timer etc. I want the timer to keep going and not stop whilst the questions are being answered!

This is my timer:

```
timer = 5
time.sleep(1)
timer -= 1
```

And my questions are generated by by defining a variable (I've shortened it down to addition):

```
def questions():
    first_number = random.randint(1, 50)
    second_number = random.randint(1, 50)
    print("What is", first_number, "+", second_number,"?")
    answer = int(input("Answer: "))
    if answer == first_number + second_number:
        print("Correct!")
        addition_score += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's harder than it should be to interrupt an `input()`.  Let's first focus on a simpler task: you want to call `questions()` repeatedly, until the total elapsed time is 60 seconds or more.  You can do that by measuring the time with `time.time()`, which returns a number of seconds since... some random "time zero" --- it doesn't matter.  Code:

```
start_time = time.time()                 # "now" at the start
while time.time() < start_time + 60:     # "not 60 seconds later"
    questions()
```

The trick is not to use `time.sleep()`: in technical terms, the `input()` call is already "blocking", and you can only have one blocking function running at the same time (unless you introduce threads or multiple processes, which is completely overkill here).

The last question, if answered correctly, will count as +1, even though it was answered after more than 60 seconds.  It's possible to change this logic by having `questions()` return either True or False, and doing the `score += 1` part only if it returned True *and* if there is still time left.

If you want to get really interrupted after exactly 60 seconds, it's slightly harder.  Try for example `signal.alarm(60)` (not on Windows).  It will deliver the signal "Alarm clock" after the given number of seconds.  By default it kills the process; if you want to catch it and do something else, try to do in addition: `signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.default_int_handler)`.  It will simulate a Ctrl-C after 60 seconds, which you can catch using:

```
try:
    while True:   # infinite loop, until interrupted
        questions()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass          # interrupted, now we're out of the loop
```

(No need for `time.time()` any more in this version.)

Comment: thanks a lot, this has really helped, i just need to figure out how to play a sound when there is 30 seconds and ten seconds remaining

Comment: Then do `signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, my_func)`; then instead of Ctrl-C, your function `my_func` will be called.  You originally set an alarm after 30 seconds, then your function plays a sound and set the next alarm after 20 more seconds, and so on.

Comment: An alternative: instead of using `signal`, you can also do `thread.start_new_thread(my_thread, ())`.  Then `my_thread()` is called once, but in parallel (in a different thread).  It would `time.sleep(30)`, play a sound, sleep more, etc., and at the end it would call `thread.interrupt_main()`.  The difference with the previous solution is that `my_thread()` is called once, but can sleep without pausing the "main thread" that runs the `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Process` from the `multiprocessing` library. Check this other answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207336/583834