# Python - Fork Modules

Tags: python, module, parallel-processing, fork

My requirement is to do something like below -

```
def task_a():
...
...
ret a1

def task_b():
...
...
ret b1

.
.

def task_z():
...
...
ret z1
```

Now in my main code I want to Execute Tasks a..z  in parallel and then wait for the return values of all of the above..

```
a = task_a()
b = task_b()
z = task_z()
```

Is there a way to call the above modules in parallel in Python?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Where have you looked for answers so far? I tried searching for `python run in parallel` and saw a bunch of useful looking results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reference:
>   [Python: How can I run python functions in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel)

Import:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
```

Add new function:

```
def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()
```

Input existing functions into the new function:

```
runInParallel(task_a, task_b, task_c...task_z)
```