# Python: running n number of functions in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I would like to call *N* number of python functions in parallel, but am not sure how to go about this.

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel) and have implemented some of the code already.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def func1():
  print 'func1: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func1: finishing'

def func2():
  print 'func2: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func2: finishing'

def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runInParallel(func1, func2)
```

That's the code from the link above. I've adapted that code to work with my situation without issue.

So with this code, I can obviously run two functions in parallel. I could just add more functions manually, (func1, func2, func3, func4, ...). That seems messy and unpythonic.

Is there a way to re-do this code to call any number of functions in parallel?

Comment: have a look at this other post, maybe can be useful:
[Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: @Carlo1585 Yes, that's the post I linked to. From that I figured out how to run multiple functions in parallel... But if I want to run say 20 functions in parallel, I don't want to have to write the code for all 20 functions. I'd like to be able to call one function 20 times, but in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the Process class ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)) for example:

```
p = Process(target=func, args=('func1', ))
```

and `func` looks like:

```
def func(name):
    print '%s: starting' % name
    for i in xrange(10000000): pass
    print '%s: finishing' % name
```

As a side note you might want to be using `Thread` instead of `Process` - see here for a comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046201/419115

Answer (score 1):

you can use `multiprocessing.Pool.map` or `imap`

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):                    # the function to be executed in parallel
    for i in xrange(10000000): pass

pool = Pool(processes=4)     # 4 worker processes
print pool.map(f, range(20)) # 20 jobs, a list will be returned when all are finished
```

alternatively you can get results as soon as they're finished using

```
for result in pool.imap(f, range(20))
    print result
```