# Parallelizing a function call in python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, subprocess

I have a function in python which I need to execute it multiple times and at the same time (to save computational cost).
The following is a simple example and I don't know how to call my function at the same time!

```
def f(x):
    return x

y1=f(x1)
y2=f(x2)
```

I need to execute y1 and y2 at the same time and wait until both finish and save the results.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: [running python functions in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to read the https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html documentation, which has a great example. If you're using Python 3.x

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

If you're using python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: multiprocessing Pools are definitely the way to go, but PLEASE read all the warning notes in the docs!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm new to python and when I run this code in IDLE, I get this error, while I should print out [1,4,9]                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mohammad/Desktop/r.py", line 8, in <module>
    with Pool(5) as p:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: If you're using python 2.x (like python 2.7), use the instructions here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html

I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @AbrahamB  I'm wondering if number 5 shows the parallelization? all the 3 inputs will be executed at the same time? if one of them returns longer than the others, it doesnt crash?

Comment: @Mohammad, per: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool: 

`processes is the number of worker processes to use.`

Comment: @AbrahamB tnx again. In windows it is working fine, but when I run it in Linux, I think there is a bug for multiprocessing and nothing happens when I run the code! not even an error!

Comment: That's probably a large enough issue for a whole new question :)

I am able to run it fine on my linux box, but there can be many differences such as python version, OS bits, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that might help you:

```
import Queue
import threading

# your function with a slight change:
def f(q,x):
    q.put(x)

inputs = [1,2,3,4]

# aggregate to a queue:
q = Queue.Queue()

for x in inputs:
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(q,x))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

outputs = q.get()
print outputs
```

> output: 1

Here `q` holds the return value of `f`.

In any case I suggest you try and read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I'm new to python, I don't know how to execute the file! As I understood, it should calls the f, 4 times in parallel and we should have 4 results in the output?

Comment: For every `q.get()` the return value is the output.