# Run different classifiers/algorithms in parallel using Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have a dataset and I wanted to test different classifiers in parallel using Spark with Python.
For example, if I want to test a Decision Tree and a Random Forest, how could I run them in parallel?

I have tried a few approaches but I keep getting:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I was trying to do this (which had worked well using scikit-learn's classifiers instead of Spark's:

```
def apply_classifier(clf, train_dataset, test_dataset):
    model = clf.fit(train_dataset)

    predictions = model.transform(test_dataset)

    evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
    evaluator.evaluate(predictions)

    return [(model, predictions)]

...

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", maxDepth=3)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures")

classifiers = [dt, rf]

sc.parallelize(classifiers).flatMap(lambda x: apply_classifier(x, train_dataset, test_dataset)).collect()
```

Any suggestions on how I can manage to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Multi-model evaluator is under development right now

Comment: thank you for your answer @T.Gawęda so there's no way around it at the moment?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if you will paralellize submitting the jobs, it still will be queued in cluster manager. But let's wait, maybe someone will have some tested workaround - I just pointed that it's not currently supported out of the box, but will be supported in near future :)

Answer (score 0):

@larissa-leite

To overcome this, I'm using `[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)` like explained in that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207336/7024760).

This is the code of the thread:

```html
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1():
  print 'func1: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func1: finishing'

def func2():
  print 'func2: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func2: finishing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=func2)
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

Just explain why I'm using this: I trained several text classifier models (more than 200) using [OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) and I need to span out every model the text that I receive.

The latency here it's less than 200ms to get all predictions to me ([the baseline time reaction](https://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime) for the human being can be something between 100ms to 420ms) so this 'latency' it's not a big deal for me.