# python tkinter, how run two commands on click on one button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How to run two commands on click on one button ?

## Example:

```
def commend1():
  print "hi"

def commend2():
  print "hello"

#TKinter
button = Button(root, commend= ?)
```

> I want them to run at the same time

Comment: You probably mean one after another. At the same time and one after another is huge difference!

Comment: You probably mean one after another : no
 At the same time and one : yes I want that

Answer (score 3):

The most basic answer for that would be:

```
def commend1():
  print "hi"

def commend2():
  print "hello"

def cmd12():
  commend1()
  commend2()

#TKinter
button = Button(root, command=cmd12)
```

Comment: You don't want the parentheses after `cmd12`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/3714930).

Comment: Yup, thanks. edited!

Comment: Do not work at the same time (run commend1 then commend2) , I want to work at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can have your commend1() to call commend2() like this :

```
def commend1():
  print "hi"
  commend2()

def commend2():
  print "hello"

#TKinter
button = Button(root, command= commend1)
```

Comment: Or you can try einsweniger's answer too

Comment: Do not work at the same time (run commend1 then commend2) , I want to work at the same time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel Check out this question. It may solve your query