# How to run one python function at the same time as another Function it depends on

Tags: python-3.x, function, deque

Im building a webscraper, i am facing an issue where the search page only provides links to the items, so i would like

function 1 read postcodes from .txt file and search for links to items

function 2 take links of items and scrape for details

I have both scrapers as seperate .py files

i have combined them together and made each script a function

i have implemented deque to add data and retrieve data and this works. but how to i get them both to run together?

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
import csv
from collections import deque

dq = deque([])

#Search The links Via Post Code

def linkScrape():
    recordnum = 0
    pagnum = 0
    with open("catlist.txt") as catlist:
        postkeys = []
        for line in catlist:
            postkeys.append(line.strip())
    with open("pcodnum.txt") as pagesnum:
        postpages = []
        for line in pagesnum:
            postpages.append(line.strip())
    with open("pcodes.txt") as pcodes:
        postcodes = []
        for line in pcodes:
            postcodes.append(line.strip())
    for y in postcodes:
        for z in postkeys:
            for x in postpages:
                surl = 'https://www.checkatrade.com/Search/?location={}&cat={}&page={}'.format(y, z, x)
                options = Options()
                options.headless = True
                driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
                #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
                driver.get (surl)
                print ("Link Scraper: Headless Firefox Scraping: " + surl)
                html = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                questions = soup.select('.ch-listing__result')
                for question in questions:
                    comlink = question.find('a', attrs={"class": "catnow-search-click"})
                    if comlink is None:
                        comlink = 'None'
                    else:
                        comlink = comlink.attrs['href']
                    comlink = 'https://www.checkatrade.com' + comlink
                    recordnum += 1
                    dq.appendleft(str(comlink))
                pagnum += 1
                print("Link Scraper: " + str(pagnum) + ' pages finished with ' + str(recordnum) + ' records')
                print(list(dq))
                driver.close()




# Scrape Company Details From Url
def datScrape( xurl ):
    f = csv.writer(open('companydetails.csv', 'w'))
    f.writerow(['Business Name', 'Business Owner', 'Business Telephone', 'Business Mobile', 'Business Email', 'Business Managed Email'])
    surl = xurl
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
    driver.get (surl)
    print ("Company Details Scraper: Headless Firefox Scraping: " + surl)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    details = soup.select('.contact-card__details')
    #print(questions)
    for detail in details:
        busname = detail.select('h1')[0].get_text()
        #print(busname)
        #busowner = question.find(class_='contact-card__contact-name').get_text()
        busowner = detail.find('div', attrs={"class": "contact-card__contact-name"})
        if busowner is None:
            busowner = 'None'
        else:
            busowner = busowner.text
        #print(busowner)
        comtelephone = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_ctlTel"})
        if comtelephone is None:
            comtelephone = 'None'
        else:
            comtelephone = comtelephone.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        #print(comtelephone)
        comtelemob = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_ctlMobile"})
        if comtelemob is None:
            comtelemob = 'None'
        else:
            comtelemob = comtelemob.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        #print(comtelemob)
        comemail = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_ctlEmail"})
        if comemail is None:
            comemail = 'None'
        else:
            comemail = comemail.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        comemanmail = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_managedEmail"})
        if comemanmail is None:
            comemanmail = 'None'
        else:
            comemanmail = comemanmail.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        #print(comemail)
        print("Company Details Scraper: " + busname + "\n" + busowner + "\n" + comtelephone + "\n" + comtelemob + "\n" + comemail + "\n" + comemanmail)
        f.writerow([busname, busowner, comtelephone, comtelemob, comemail, comemanmail])
    data_list = []
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
from multiprocessing import Process

p = Process(target=linkScrape)
p.start()
p2 = Process(target=datScrape)
sleep(20)
p2.start(dq.pop())

p.join()
p2.join()
```

Updated Code With Multi Processing
new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 120, in <module>
    p2.start(dq.pop())
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

even thought the queue definitley has data at this point

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you'll probably need to include some `multiprocessing`. See [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for some more details.

You may consider reviewing [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel) for a similar issue. What you are going to need to do is create processes for each.

I would consider changing your script to the following:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
import csv
from collections import deque
# Added this library
from multiprocessing import Process

dq = deque([])

#Search The links Via Post Code

def linkScrape( scrapeInput ):
    recordnum = 0
    pagnum = 0
    spost = scrapeInput
    with open("catlist.txt") as catlist:
        postkeys = []
        for line in catlist:
            postkeys.append(line.strip())
    with open("pcodnum.txt") as pagesnum:
        postpages = []
        for line in pagesnum:
            postpages.append(line.strip())
    for z in postkeys:
        for x in postpages:
            surl = 'https://www.checkatrade.com/Search/?location=' + spost + '&cat=' + str(z) + '&page=' + str(x)
            options = Options()
            options.headless = True
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
            #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
            driver.get (surl)
            print ("Headless Firefox Scraping: " + surl)
            html = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            questions = soup.select('.ch-listing__result')
            for question in questions:
                comlink = question.find('a', attrs={"class": "catnow-search-click"})
                if comlink is None:
                    comlink = 'None'
                else:
                    comlink = comlink.attrs['href']
                comlink = 'https://www.checkatrade.com' + comlink
                recordnum += 1
                dq.appendleft(comlink)
            pagnum += 1
            print("Link Scraper: " + str(pagnum) + ' pages finished with ' + str(recordnum) + ' records')
            driver.close()




# Scrape Company Details From Url
def datScrape( xurl ):
    f = csv.writer(open('companydetails.csv', 'w'))
    f.writerow(['Business Name', 'Business Owner', 'Business Telephone', 'Business Mobile', 'Business Email', 'Business Managed Email'])
    surl = xurl
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
    driver.get (surl)
    print ("Headless Firefox Scraping: " + surl)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    details = soup.select('.contact-card__details')
    #print(questions)
    for detail in details:
        busname = detail.select('h1')[0].get_text()
        #print(busname)
        #busowner = question.find(class_='contact-card__contact-name').get_text()
        busowner = detail.find('div', attrs={"class": "contact-card__contact-name"})
        if busowner is None:
            busowner = 'None'
        else:
            busowner = busowner.text
        #print(busowner)
        comtelephone = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_ctlTel"})
        if comtelephone is None:
            comtelephone = 'None'
        else:
            comtelephone = comtelephone.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        #print(comtelephone)
        comtelemob = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_ctlMobile"})
        if comtelemob is None:
            comtelemob = 'None'
        else:
            comtelemob = comtelemob.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        #print(comtelemob)
        comemail = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_ctlEmail"})
        if comemail is None:
            comemail = 'None'
        else:
            comemail = comemail.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        comemanmail = detail.find('a', attrs={"id": "ctl00_ctl00_content_managedEmail"})
        if comemanmail is None:
            comemanmail = 'None'
        else:
            comemanmail = comemanmail.attrs['href'].rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
        #print(comemail)
        print("Company Details Scraper: " + busname + "\n" + busowner + "\n" + comtelephone + "\n" + comtelemob + "\n" + comemail + "\n" + comemanmail)
        f.writerow([busname, busowner, comtelephone, comtelemob, comemail, comemanmail])
    data_list = []
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

# Added in this function to run two functions in parallel
# Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel
# Credit to NPE
def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()

with open("pcodes.txt") as pcodes:
    postcodes = []
    for line in pcodes:
        postcodes.append(line.strip())

# You will probably need to edit the below...
for postcode in postcodes:
    # You will need to call the runInParallel function to call your two other functions
    runInParallel(linkScrape(postcode), datScrape(postcode))
```

It may require a bit of editing since it's unclear if you really want two things to occur simultaneously since you have an `IF` statement, but this would accomplish both functions running at (as close as possible) the same time.

Comment: yeah i tried this ```from multiprocessing import Process

p = Process(target=linkScrape)
p.start()
p2 = Process(target=datScrape)
sleep(20)
p2.start(dq.pop())

p.join()
p2.join()``` and it gives error ``` IndexError: pop from an empty deque
``` but if i print the que there is stuff in there

Comment: and no not simultaneously, just function 2 read an excute the data from function 1 automatically