# How to parallel execution of multiple Python code in Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

How can I execute three or more Python scripts in parallel?

Currently I am executing three Python scripts in three different consoles of [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29).

Comment: Please provide more details. Show code and explain in detail what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Lets say i have three scripts a.py, b.py,c.py. Now how to execute these python scripts in parallel

Comment: The main question would be _why_. But running different terminals is the best way, indeed. (Or if you're on linux, this is easily done with running different `screen`s.)

Comment: This answer to the question is "This is for automated algotrading" wherin my goal is to schedule each scripts to run at specific time every day

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to import all the scripts and then simultaneously execute them in a function.

Comment: I would still be sequential one after the other, if first script takes 30 minutes, then second script has to wait for 30 minutes, These scripts needs to be executed parallel

Comment: That is true unless you utilize the multiprocessing module please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138825/8405902