# printing dots using decorator while a function execute

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to write  a decorator that will print dots in terminal while the function that calls the decorator executes.

```
import sys
from time import sleep


def call_counter(func):
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        for dot in xrange(0, 99):
            sys.stdout.write(".")
            sys.stdout.flush()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    helper.calls = 0
    helper.__name__= func.__name__
    return helper

@call_counter
def f():
    sleep(10)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    f()
```

this is what I have tried so far. But i am not getting expected result.
for function taking time to execute I have used sleep of 10 seconds .

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: I get a single dot  while waiting for 10 seconds

Comment: I thought that is what you expected to get? What *did* you expect?

Comment: continuous printing of dot while the `f` function exectues.
in this case for 10 seconds

Comment: But `helper` just writes a single dot before calling `func` and blocking while it is running. You need some sort of concurrency.

Comment: I believe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel

Comment: I have updated the decorator function ,  that prints dots, but now it straight away print 100 dots.  if I use concurrency, then how should I register the calling function is complete ? do you get what I mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use decorators or not you cannot magically print the progress of a function without having this function willingly reporting its progress. Reporting the progress is usually done by passing a `progress` callback to the function. The function will at eg each iteration of an internal loop (provided it has some sort of loop) execute the user callback and pass a parameter denoting its current progress.
something like

```
def long_func(data:list, progress):
tot = len(data)
for i,item in enumerate(data):
   #do something with item
   progress(i+1/tot)
```

Comment: in my long  running function actually make call to a `subprocess.Popen` that takes long time not that there is something iterative that takes time. if it was an iterative I could have easily printed the progress and this post on SO wouldnt have existed.