# Python: multiprocessing Queue seemingly unaccessible

Tags: python

I am confused why this code seems to hang and do nothing?  As I try to experiment, it seems that I cannot get functions to access the queue from outside the function that added the item to the queue.  Sorry, I am pretty novice.  Do I need to pip install something?  Update: Win10, Python 3.7.8, and this problem seems to apply to other variables besides queues.

This code works:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

q = Queue()

def main():
    q.put('a')
    q.put('b')
    print(q.get(block=True) + ' gotten')
    print(q.get(block=True) + ' gotten')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code does not work:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

q = Queue()

def main():
    putter_process = Process(target=putter)
    putter_process.start()
    print(q.get(block=True) + ' gotten')
    print(q.get(block=True) + ' gotten')

def putter():
    q.put('a')
    q.put('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Similarly, this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905169/in-python-what-is-the-best-practice-for-running-parallel-processes-where-one-is/62905439?noredirect=1#comment111262829_62905439) also hangs up on me:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

sensor_data_queue = Queue()


def reads_sensor_data():
    # Suppose we add a sensor reading every second; this simulates that. It runs 10 iterations. You could modify this
    # to run forever, or until something tells it to quit.

    for iteration in range(10):
        sensor_data_queue.put(random.random())  # Generate a random number.
        time.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second

    sensor_data_queue.put(None)  # None means we're done.


def analyze_sensor_data():
    while 1:
        data = sensor_data_queue.get(block=True)
        if data is None:
            break
        else:
            print(f'Analyzing {data}... Beep, beep, boop... {data * 100}')
    print('All done!')

def main():
    # Run the reader process in the background...
    reader_process = Process(target=reads_sensor_data)
    reader_process.start()
    try:
        analyze_sensor_data()
    finally:
        reader_process.join()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:  I am not sure this has to do with queues, because when I try to change a regular text variable it also doesn't work.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time

text = 'start'

def main():
    putter_process = Process(target=putter)
    putter_process.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(text)

def putter():
    text = 'edited'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above outputs `start` whereas I was expecting it to output `edited`

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Win10.  Python 3.7.8

Comment: I made an edit to show some simpler code that is also not working. Thanks everyone for looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm. I tested the example I gave you on Linux, and your second block code, which you say doesn't work, *does work for me on Linux*. I looked up the docs and indeed, [Windows appears to be a special case](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Global variables
>
> Bear in mind that if code run in a child process tries to access a global variable, then the value it sees (if any) may not be the same as the value in the parent process at the time that Process.start was called.
>
> However, global variables which are just module level constants cause no problems.

## Solution

I can't test this because I don't have your operating system available, but I would try passing the queue then to each of your functions. To follow your example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def main():
    q = Queue()

    putter_process = Process(target=putter, args=(q,))
    putter_process.start()
    print(q.get(block=True) + ' gotten')
    print(q.get(block=True) + ' gotten')

def putter(q):
    q.put('a')
    q.put('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Based on my interpretation of the docs, that *should work* on Windows, but I can't say I've tested it myself.

## Note on tuples

In your other question, you asked why the trailing comma is relevant in `args=`. Let me show you:

```py
>>> my_string = 'hello, world!'
>>> type(my_string)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(my_string)
hello, world!
```

As you can see, I've created a string variable. Now, let me create a tuple, which is like a list, but [varies in some important ways](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/).

```py
>>> my_tuple = ('hello, world', 'hola mundo')
>>> type(my_tuple)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> print(my_tuple)
('hello, world', 'hola mundo')
```

As you can see, I've created a tuple with two elements, each element being a string. But what if I want to create a tuple with just one element? This **will not work**:

```py
>>> my_not_a_tuple = ('hello, world')
>>> type(my_not_a_tuple)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(my_not_a_tuple)
hello, world
```

As you can see, I've only created a string. But I *can* create a tuple with one element by adding a comma, which clarifies that the parentheses are there to show that it's a tuple, not to control the order of operations:

```py
>>> my_tuple = ('hello, world',)
>>> type(my_tuple)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> print(my_tuple)
('hello, world',)
```

That extra comma matters because you're needing to pass a tuple, not a string.

Comment: Thank you, I confirmed your code works on Win10 Python 3.7.8. I read about tuples and then is it true that making the argument a tuple means the arg is passed by reference instead of by value?  Again, I really appreciate the detailed answer.  I would have thought that a process could take an object as a parameter, not just a tuple containing that object.

Comment: No problem. No, isn't that it's passed by value. It's that when you pass args, it must be a tuple or list; you can't pass args to the Process using anything other than a sequence. So you could do args=[1,2,3] or args=(1,2,3) -- tuples are just more efficient.

Comment: FYI, in Python 3+, everything is always passed only by reference. But for simple types (strings, integers, etc), they *seem like* they're passed by value because those objects are immutable and cannot be changed.