# How to use python threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I want to be able to have two procedures run at the same time, current code below;

```
import time,threading

def procedure1():
    for i in range(0,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('hello')

def procedure2():
    for j in range(0,10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(j)

thread1=procedure1()
thread2=procedure2()

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

However this makes the two procedures run one after the other rather than parallel as I will require. Just need this example completed to work and will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207336/5413636

Comment: Your code is NOT using threading at all. See https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ for getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import `threading` but don't use it. Try:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=procedure1)
```