# How do I run two looping functions parallel to each other?

Tags: python

I've been trying to run two infinitely looping functions parallel to each other with python, but just calling both functions on separate lines seems to not be working because the second function never actually gets called when I'm running the code.

Comment: One thread runs procedural (one line after the other). You need multiple threads: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207336/1401798

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The question is about running two codes simultaneously. It's unclear if this means concurrently or parallel.

Comment: @jabaa fair point.

Comment: Looping sounds like a CPU bounded task. Maybe you want to take a look at concurrent.future ProcessPoolExecutor?

Comment: I would be running them parallel to each other