# How to achieve closure via scoped variables in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an array of functions that I then execute in Parallel. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207336/3114742) answer on SO, and so have a POC script like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def runInParallel(*fns):
  processes = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
  for p in processes:
    p.join()

fns = []

def hi(x):
  print(x) # This always prints out '5'

for i in range(6):
  fns.append(lambda: hi(i))

runInParallel( *fns)
```

My intention is that the body of the lambda function would be closure over the value of the `i` variable at the time of lambda definition. But this is not occurring. Instead when I execute the functions all the `i` values are '5'.

How can I create closure over a variable in a for loop?

Comment: Consider using `functools.partial`: `[functools.partial(hi, i) for i in range(6)]`

Comment: Although, since your function is always the same and only the argument changes, you may want to use a multiprocessing Pool and `.map()` instead, since then you can pass a list of function arguments that will be iterated over.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop answer your question?

Comment: So, see the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/5014455)