# How can I simultaneously run two (or more) functions in python?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, video-processing

I intend to be able to play video via opencv *while* some other process runs in the background. My current working looks like this

```
import cv2
async def function1():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
    while  True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            cap.release()
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
            ret, frame = cap.read()

async def function2():
    while True:
        print("Inside Function 2")

async def main():
    f1=loop.create_task(function1())
    f2 =loop.create_task(function2())
    await asyncio.gather(f1,f2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
asyncio.run(main())
```

expecting that while my video continuously plays, function 2 will also continuously run (in this example printing "inside function 2"). But with this script only the video plays and function 2 is never invoked: how can I run both function 1 and function 2 simultaneously so that while my video is playing function 2 also continuously prints?

Answer (score 0):

Try Threading instead of async/await
so you can have multiple threads(subprograms) running at the same time