# How to run adb commands through python?

Tags: python

I've ten different adb commands and want to execute it concurrently as a separate process . I've used subprocess module & but process doesn't seem to run concurrently. Is there an efficient method in python to run process concurrently? My code snippet is below

```
def run(com):
       sub = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return sub.communicate()
cmd =[adb commands 1 to 10]
for i in cmd:
   run(i)
```

Comment: I guess this can be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("adb devices",shell=True)
```

Here in place of "adb devices" you can write any adb commands.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop `sub.communicate()`.

> `Popen.communicate(input=None)` Interact with process: Send data to
>   stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.
>   **Wait for process to terminate**. The optional input argument should be a
>   string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be
>   sent to the child.

Comment: None of stuff listed in quoted docs would be performed, including waiting for process to terminate. So none of previous processes would block creating new.

Answer (score 0):

**Running ADB through python**

Although it might seem complicated, its actually pretty easy. You can use:

1. python-pure-adb.

Install it using `pip install python-pure-adb`. You can also take a look at the documentation, which will help you out.