# How do I run several functions in parallel each with it's own set of inputs?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
def func1(a,b,c)
    # Does some complex things
    return processed_output

def func2(a,b,c)
    # Does some else that is also complex things
    return processed_output

def parallelWrapperFunction(func1(a,b,c), func2(e,f,g))
    # Runs everything in parallel
    return func1_output, func2_output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get function inputs a,b,c,d,e,f
    parallelWrapperFunction(func1(a,b,c), func2(e,f,g))
```

How do I go about setting this up? I'd like to use separate cores so I can bypass the global interpreter lock. I've seen suggestions to use the multiprocessing package in python. Just need to know how to go about doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Executing multiple functions simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously)

Comment: I've tried that code actually, but i don't know how pass arguments and get the return values back.

Comment: You can use the `args` argument of `Process` to pass arguments to your function, and you can pass `multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Manager` alongside so your functions can write to them instead of returning a value. There are examples of all that available in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Thanks zwer, I'll try to figure it out from here.