# How to have multiple functions with sleep function running?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am working on pulling weather data from a number of sources online, here is some of my code to get this data.

```
import wunderground as wg
import weatherScraper as wp

def main():
    wg.main()
    ws.main()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Both of the main functions contain sleep functions. I was wondering if it would be possible to run both simultaneously? Currently it runs one, has the sleep function activate, and such.

Comment: You are looking for [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: You need to run one (or both) on separate threads in the background. Note, this has the potential to add a *lot* of complexity if you aren't ready for it, so be sure to read up thoroughly on Multithreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. If you don't want to make one script for each function, you may use the `multiprocessing` module and use the `Process` object. There is a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18865028/6749871), of course without using a global variable. Also you may check the module documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

I think your code would be like this:

```
import wunderground as wg
import weatherScraper as wp
from multiprocessing import Process

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    p1 = Process(target = wg.main())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = ws.main())
    p2.start()
```

Or you may use another parallel modules like the ones listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) on the Symmetric Multiprocessing section.

Cheers.

Comment: I ended up using threading, and was wondering what the difference between multiprocessing and threading are?

Comment: @Professor_Joykill You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044626/6749871)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Maybe something like:

```
import wunderground as wg
import weatherScraper as wp
from multiprocessing import Process

f1 = wg.main
f2 = ws.main

p1 = Process(target=f1)
p2 = Process(target=f2)
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

See [Python: Executing multiple functions simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously)