# Parallel functions in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have these functions in my python script the top three of them being related to tkinter and the bottom one being a process not related to the Tk window , how can i execute the **pixels()** function parallel to the tkinter functions ?

```
top.mainloop()
C.pack()
colors()
pixels()
```

Comment: use the threading module to start pixels in a seperate thread

Comment: Have you done *any* research on the topic? **If yes**, what are your findings? Refer to the articles you read, show what you have tried, explain what did not work. **If not**... why not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously i tried this thread but due to having multiple functions both related and unrelated to each other  I found myself conufsed with the way I am supposed to implement multiprocessing (i am quite new to python syntax and some stuff is a bit strange)

Answer (score -2):

Try tkinter's `after` method. Documentation [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).

I see a lot of people who are looking for "running function along side tkinter mainloop" but cannot find `after` while researching. I guess it just isn't talked about much in documentation to show up on searches (besides SO questions).

Comment: the function i try to run in parallel with the tkinter window is not related to the window and I need an endless loop to be running inside the pixels() function and that's thy after does not help me in this situation.

Comment: `after` doesn't run code in parallel. Tkinter is single threaded, so it can only  run one line of code at a time.

Comment: @BryanOakley and here I am thinking `after` used a different thread. Thank you for telling me.