# How to run multiple functions with different return values in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have multiple functions to train different classifiers, each function returns some related output parametes. The execution time of each is slightly long, so I want to take advantage of `multiprocessing`.

For example:

```
test_mthd = 'complete'
row_num = 288
prob_scores_ANN = test_ANN(test_dataset,test_labels, test_mthd, row_num, 
                       input_hidden_weights, hidden_output_weights, 
                       input_hidden_bias, hidden_output_bias)
predictions_KNN= eval_KNN(trainingSet,testSet, test_mthd, row_num)
```

Now,

```
from multiprocessing import Process
if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=building_tree_CART(trainingSet, depth_cond=8, min_cond=1))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target= train_ANN(training_data,training_labels))  
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Inspiration for this is from: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously)

I think its a typo error: I changed `training` to `target`, and `p1` runs and then `p2` starts. and how do we return values from each function?

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: Unluckily "an error" is the worst error of all when it comes to diagnosing it. Please add a detailed error description and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation of multiprocessing module. [link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#examples)

To retrieve values when using `mp.process` you have to use `mp.queue`. I find this way of multiprocessing a bit too detailed, you could explore `mp.Pool` instead.

However, for your example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process


def building_tree_CART(p1queue)
    trainingSet, depth_cond, min_cond = p1queue.get()
    #do stuff
    p1queue.put(variable)

def train_ANN(p2queue)
    training_data,training_labels = p2queue.get()
    #...
    p2queue.put(result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    #create separate instances of queues for processes
    p1queue = Queue()
    p1queue.put(trainingSet, 8, 1)
    p2queue = Queue()
    p2queue.put(training_data, training_labels)
    #Process targets a function, arguments are passed separately
    p1 = Process(target=building_tree_CART, args=p1queue)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=train_ANN, args=p2queue)  
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    returned_variable = p1queue.get()
    p2.join()
    returned_variable2 = p2queue.get()
```

From the limited information you provided this is the best guess. In case you need to run functions multiple times, I suggest you use `mp.Pool.map` or `mp.Pool.apply`. For my own purposes I have found `mp.Pool.apply_async` to be the fastest and the most convenient way of using `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: I get error while running this: `
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-168-e7200665b8c6>", line 1, in <module>
    p2queue.put(training_data, training_labels)

  File "C:\Users\dana0941\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 82, in put
    if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: the same error for the first function call too, I adjusted my functions as you suggested and put `output_variables` in `p1queue.put(output_variables)`