# Is there a way in Python to fire two lines at once?

Tags: python

I have been working on a small project of mine.
It's pretty much a robot that goes forward using a gyroscope. I am aiming for very high accuracy in this case.

I have two commands, which stop the motors. The problem is that there's a small delay between the two and I constantly get 3-5mm errors on the same motor (the one that gets stopped one line later).

Due to the nature of my program, I cannot tell that specific motor to 'do 3-5 mm less'. Is there a way I could speed this up in any way?

```
def stop_motors():
    p1 = Process(target=stop_left());
    p2 = Process(target=stop_right());
    p1.start();
    p2.start();

def stop_left():
    MotorLeft.stop(stop_action='hold');
    MotorLeft.reset();

def stop_right():
    MotorRight.stop(stop_action='hold');
    MotorRight.reset();
```

I tried this, same results.

Comment: How are you sending those two commands?

Comment: you could perform the motor stop in 2 threads, synchronized on an event. That'd be better if the GIL doesn't get in the way

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18865028/1586200) could help.

Comment: If you need real-time responsiveness, Python may not be the right language for the job. Yes, it supports threading, but no, using threading won't *guarantee* that your timing is what you want it to be.

Comment: Currently for testing I import a .py file directly into the python interpreter (using `;` to split the lines, why? because I am too impatient to wait for that frustrating 7 seconds in between syncing, and all the startup phase of my program)

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar yes, but the overhead of spawning 2 new processes may aggravate the delay for both motors. Threads would be better (same principle)

Comment: How much work is done in these two commands? They likely do some I/O which usually releases the GIL and lets another thread run. In that case, threads would likely work.

Comment: add some code/your attempt to your question to make it more accurate, and you'll have my vote (and maybe answers)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am working on what Parag S. ... said, that looks promising.

Comment: Do these two commands need to be sent in order?

Comment: yes, try with threads too, response time will be better

Comment: (For that matter, *Linux* isn't a RTOS, and doesn't offer real-time guarantees even from the kernel layer; there's a reason people pay money for vxWorks when building embedded systems where timing is mission- or safety-critical).

Comment: What is eating up the several ms? If you are doing more work than just sending the commands, then you may need to prestage everything then send the commands. `cmd1 = gen_stage1_cmd();cmd2 = gen_stage2_cmd();send_cmds((cmd1, cmd2))`.

Comment: @tdelaney No, I really just want to stop both at the same time.

Comment: err `target=stop_left()` should be `target=stop_left` else it calls the function instead of passing the function pointer. A classic... also drop the semicolons, python doesn't need them

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah I know about the semi colons, I pass all of that through the console so that's why I need them. Maybe using the console is also slowing things down?

Comment: never mind that, the most important thing is to _drop the parentheses_ read my comment again.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Just tried that, and it works! Thanks to everyone!