# Python3 multiprocessing or multithreading way to use getter/setter in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, ray

Let's say I have classes where I define attributes as getter/setter. Classes are like this one:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "default name"

    @property
    def myname(self):
        self._myname = self.name
        return self._myname

    @myname.setter
    def myname(self, n):
        self._myname = n
        self.name = self._myname
```

I instance these classes. In this example I instance several times this same class:

```
a = TestClass()
a.myname = "A"
b = TestClass()
b.myname = "B"
```

Setting and getting these names requires a certain amount of time.

How can I get in parallel `a.myname` and `b.myname`?
How can I set in parallel `a.myname = "new A"` and `b.myname = new B`?

The examples that I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/how-to-run-functions-in-parallel), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python) with `multiprocessing`, `multithreading` only involve functions or standard class methods.
Moreover, a solution based on `ray` apparently does not allow to access class attributes.

Comment: Why are `_myname` and `name` separate attributes? Why even bother with properties when the name is both readable and writable and there's no clear need for programmatic behavior?

Comment: Because I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible. True setter and getter involves a `request.get()` and a `request.put()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering how you'd use properties as functions

You can directly access the underlying getter and setter function if needed, and manually pass the instance to them, e.g. replacing:

```
a.myname = "A"
```

with:

```
type(a).myname.fset(a, "A")
```

For simpler usage, you could expose the functions as both functions and `property`s, e.g:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "default name"

    def get_myname(self):
        self._myname = self.name
        return self._myname

    def set_myname(self, n):
        self._myname = n
        self.name = self._myname

    myname = property(get_myname, set_myname)
```

so you could directly replace:

```
a.myname = "A"
```

with:

```
a.set_myname("A")
```

without needing to manually bypass the descriptor protocol, while still allowing `a.myname = "A"` to continue working when it's not needed for parallel processing.

#### Addressing the XY problem here

All that said, **this is a bad use case for properties**. Properties, as a rule, should be low overhead, because from the perspective of someone reading code using them, they *look* like attribute access and should behave roughly like attribute access, e.g. they not require multiple orders of magnitude greater time to access than regular attribute access. If your "property" requires non-local network operations, it's not suitable to act as a property; use dedicated getter and setter functions and don't provide a property at all, so consumers of your API aren't deceived into thinking the access can be done cheaply. By not using properties, your problem disappears; you're back to methods, which can be parallelized.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, althoug I am not allowed to edit the classes. WoW! Then I guess that another option is to use `getattr` and `setattr`, right?

Comment: @leonardvertighel: Yeah. Or just write a wrapper function to do the job.