# I've two functions both have for loop each, All I want is too run the function one by one with one iteration only

Tags: python, multithreading, function, loops

MY code:-

```
def looping():
for i in range(1,4):
    print('*')

def not_looping():
for j in range(1,4):
    print('-')

looping()
not_looping()
```

Output I got:-

```
*
*
*
-
-
-
```

Output I want

```
*
-
*
-
*
-
```

I've also visited this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously), And applied my logic as per the post, But still It's providing me same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want generators?

```
def a_gen():
    for _ in range(4):
        yield "*"

def b_gen():
    for _ in range(4):
        yield "-"


ag = a_gen()
bg = b_gen()

while (a := next(ag, None)) and (b := next(bg, None)):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Note: This while loop will terminate as soon as one of the two generators has been exhausted. In this case, both generators happen to yield the same number of objects.

Comment: I got your code it works properly but what if the values are different suppose if range is not same then what will be the output

Comment: In that case, the while loop will end as soon as the "shorter" generator is exhausted, and the remaining objects in the other generator will not be yielded/printed. What's your actual use-case?

Comment: Actually I've heard of generators but never used it, So I had ask about mixed range in the comment. But Thank you you're code worked for me.