# BTC Price Across Different Crypto Exchanges

Tags: python, binance, coinbase-api, ccxt, kraken.com

I am trying to use CCXT to get the BTC bid and ask price across different exchanges, but running the code sequencially cannot get the price of a given moment correctly. Is there any way to execute them at the same time and return the correct price?

```
import ccxt

binance = ccxt.binance()
coinbase = ccxt.coinbase()
ftx = ccxt.ftx()
kraken = ccxt.kraken()
kucoin = ccxt.kucoin()

stat_list = binance.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
print('Binance', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


stat_list = coinbase.fetchTicker('BTC-USD')
print('Coinbase', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


stat_list = ftx.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
print('FTX', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


stat_list = kraken.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
print('Kraken', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


stat_list = kucoin.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
print('Kucoin', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])
```

Output:

```
Binance 20451.04 20451.33
Coinbase 20343.33 20552.61
FTX 20451.0 20452.0
Kraken 20454.5 20454.6
Kucoin 20450.9 20451.0
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously) help?

Answer (score 1):

With help from Ari Cooper-Davis, this is what I come up with. It seems like the bid and ask prices between the exchanges are still quite large.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import ccxt


def func1():
    binance = ccxt.binance()
    stat_list = binance.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
    print('Binance', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


def func2():
    coinbase = ccxt.coinbase()
    stat_list = coinbase.fetchTicker('BTC-USD')
    print('Coinbase', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


def func3():
    ftx = ccxt.ftx()
    stat_list = ftx.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
    print('FTX', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


def func4():
    kraken = ccxt.kraken()
    stat_list = kraken.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
    print('Kraken', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


def func5():
    kucoin = ccxt.kucoin()
    stat_list = kucoin.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')
    print('Kucoin', stat_list['bid'], stat_list['ask'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
    p3 = Process(target=func3)
    p3.start()
    p4 = Process(target=func4)
    p4.start()
    p5 = Process(target=func5)
    p5.start()
```

Output:

```
FTX 20428.0 20429.0
Binance 20431.99 20432.15
Kucoin 20428.1 20429.6
Kraken 20430.5 20430.6
Coinbase 20311.53 20525.9
```

Answer (score 1):

In programming, we use the term *concurrency*. So our task is to fetch ticker data concurrently. There are several approaches to do this in Python.

The `multiprocessing` module can be used for fetching tickers from multiple exchanges. The example can be improved by using a pool and adding all the ticker data into a container and printing it at the end, rather than printing each ticker data separately (IO operations are relatively expensive.)

Multiprocessing is usually used for the *CPU-bound* tasks, such as intensive math calculations. Our task is *IO-bound*, that is heavy on IO operations. For these kind of tasks, we mostly use asynchronous programming.

The `ccxt` module already contains support for async programming.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import asyncio
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt


exchanges = [ccxt.binance(), ccxt.bybit(), ccxt.kucoin(), ccxt.bitpanda(),
             ccxt.kraken()]

async def get_ticker(exchange):

    data = await exchange.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT')
    await exchange.close()
    return (exchange.name, data)

async def launch():

    resps = await asyncio.gather(*map(get_ticker, exchanges))
    
    for name, data in resps:
        print(f"{name}: {data['bid']} {data['ask']}")
    

asyncio.run(launch())
```

This works by quickly launching all the (non-blocking) requests and starting a loop. The loop waits for all the responses to finish. So no task is waiting for other task to finish. In contrast, multiprocessing starts each blocking request in a separate processor/core. Both are able to do our tasks concurrently, but the asynchronous way is built-in the library, easier to use and the preferred way in IO heavy operations.